# how to find the disk usage of a directory in Unix

Tags: disk-usage

Can someone explain how this calculation is done for disk usage? I am confused because in line1 **4k** , line2 **4k** line3 **36k** and total is also **36k**

```
 $ du -ch
 4.0K   ./tempFolder
 4.0K   ./Folder1
 36K    .
36K total
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the output of `du -ch`, the last line is the total you asked for with `-c` while the second to last line is the total size of the directory you queried.

In your case of running `du` without a specified directory it uses `.`, otherwise known as the current directory.  The full size of a single queried directory is usually also the total size.  You would normally use the `-c` option when you want the total size of multiple directories passed to the `du` command, i.e. `du -ch /opt /srv /etc`

Also, the output of `du -ch` does not show sizes of individual files, just their totals in the directory.  Without knowing the contents of the directory associated with that output, I would assume you have 28k of regular files in that folder as well as those two directories.

Comment: In those 28K, there's also the directory file (`.`) itself.

Answer (score 2):

By default, `du` *shows* size counts for only directories as a whole; the counts of files (non-directories to be exact) are not shown individually but their sizes are obviously counted and added up to the size count of their parent directory.

So, in:

```
4.0K   ./tempFolder
4.0K   ./Folder1
36K    .
36K total
```

- `du` is showing size count for the current directory (as without any filesystem path argument, it defaults to `.`), recursively -- totaling in `36K`
- directories `./tempFolder` and `./Folder1` -- both has sizes of `4K` individually (again calculated recursively)

---

As a side note, to make `du` to *show* the size for individual files as well, use `-a`/`--all`:

```
-a, --all
    write counts for all files, not just directories
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this way.

```
du -ch location  | grep total
```

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. Please note, however, that the OP does not want to isolate the grand total from the output of `du`, but wants to understand how this value is calculated (in particular given that it is not simply the sum of all values on the lines above the total).